# Unable to add class using QuerySelector method

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have an input field inside the form tag in my HTML document which has an id (wow) and has a class detect. I was trying to add a class of (success) which will turn the color of input field green if the input value of user matches the desired pattern. I have selected that input tag through `queryselector` method like this --> `const addclass = document.querySelector('.detect');` but when user I type a value inside the input field I get an error (uncaught type error cannot read property set attribute of null.) The good thing is that it runs fine when I use `document.getelement` by id method. I don't know why it is showing uncaught type error when I use the query selector method.

Here is Code:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.sinup');

select.addEventListener('keyup', function(element) {
  const value = select.wow.value;
  const pattern = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/;
  const addclass = document.querySelector('.detect');
  if (pattern.test(value)) {
    addclass.setAttribute('class', 'success');
  } else {
    addclass.setAttribute('class', 'error');
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="sinup">
  <input class="detect" type="text" name="" id="wow" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <div class=" change"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hah, it's because you replace the class man.  You're removing the `detect` value from the class.  It cannot find it after the first run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies where **you trying to get the class `detect` in every `keyup` event but you replaced the `detect` in first `keyup`**, so in order to avoid it you should either define `addclass` variable before the `addEventListener`, or using `classList` to add the new class to existing one in each `keyup` event.

So your final code should be something like this:

1. **Defining `addClass` outside of `addEventLisetner`**.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.sinup');
const addclass = document.querySelector('.detect');

select.addEventListener('keyup', function(element) {
  const value = select.wow.value;
  const pattern = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/;
  console.log(addclass);
  if (pattern.test(value)) {
    addclass.setAttribute('class', 'success');
  } else {
    addclass.setAttribute('class', 'error');
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="sinup">
  <input class="detect" type="text" name="" id="wow" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <div class=" change"></div>
</form>
```

2. **Using `ClassList`**.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.sinup');

select.addEventListener('keyup', function(element) {
  const value = select.wow.value;
  const pattern = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/;
  const addclass = document.querySelector('.detect');
  console.log(addclass);
  if (pattern.test(value)) {
    addclass.classList.add("success");
    addclass.classList.remove("error");
  } else {
    addclass.classList.remove("success");
    addclass.classList.add("error");
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="sinup">
  <input class="detect" type="text" name="" id="wow" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <div class=" change"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the class of the element. So after you change the class to `success` or `error`, `document.querySelector(".detect")` no longer finds it.

Instead of replacing the class completely, you should just add and remove the `success` and `error` classes.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.sinup');

select.addEventListener('keyup', function(element) {
  const value = select.wow.value;
  const pattern = /^[a-z0-9]{6,10}$/;
  const addclass = document.querySelector('.detect');
  if (pattern.test(value)) {
    addclass.classList.add("success");
    addclass.classList.remove("error");
  } else {
    addclass.classList.remove("success");
    addclass.classList.add("error");
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="sinup">
  <input class="detect" type="text" name="" id="wow" placeholder="username"><br>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
  <div class=" change"></div>
</form>
```

In general you should avoid assigning directly to the `class` attribute, because it's common to have multiple classes for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run it, it works. It sets the class to the value you specify. But during this process, you end up REPLACING all the existing class values which you are relying on to re-identify it on the next keyup event trigger. Since it cannot find such an element -- you get `null`.

Look at using add and remove to remove individual classes rather than replacing the entire class list:

- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [DOMTokenList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)
- [DOMTokenList.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove)